# Django admin server shuts down when 127.0.0.1:<port>/admin/ URL is hit

Tags: python, django, django-manage.py

Developing my first Django project using Django docs https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.0/intro/tutorial02/

I have gotten to the admin section, but anytime I enter the `/admin/` the Django server shuts down with no error message (like pressing CTRL + C).

What I've tried
 1. Running the server on a different port
 2. Creating a new Django project
 3. Stopped python processes from task manager

It's driving me crazy because it works fine when I goto `127.0.0.1:<port>/app/index`
but server shuts down when

Below are the django server logs

```
File ...Python\Python37-32\Lib\stringprep.py first seen with mtime 1530068518.0
File ...Lib\site-packages\django\contrib\auth\migrations\0001_initial.py first seen with mtime 1575315232.7083857
File ...Lib\site-packages\django\contrib\auth\migrations\0004_alter_user_username_opts.py first seen with mtime 1575315232.7103803
File ...Lib\site-packages\django\contrib\admin\migrations\__init__.py first seen with mtime 1575315232.064109
File ...Lib\site-packages\django\contrib\contenttypes\migrations\0001_initial.py first seen with mtime 1575315232.9317892
File ...Lib\site-packages\django\contrib\auth\migrations\0005_alter_user_last_login_null.py first seen with mtime 1575315232.711378
File ...Lib\site-packages\PIL\_imaging.cp37-win32.pyd first seen with mtime 1575317072.293999
File ...Lib\site-packages\django\contrib\admin\templatetags\admin_list.py first seen with mtime 1575315232.244624
File ...Lib\site-packages\django\contrib\auth\migrations\0009_alter_user_last_name_max_length.py first seen with mtime 1575315232.7153673
File ...Lib\site-packages\django\contrib\auth\migrations\0003_alter_user_email_max_length.py first seen with mtime 1575315232.709383
(0.000) SELECT "django_session"."session_key", "django_session"."session_data", "django_session"."expire_date" FROM "django_session" WHERE ("django_session"."expire_date" > '2019-12-08 00:29:28.033564' AND "django_session"."session_key" = '2okb8vdor5ydpa06vd97opvzhuqyxt51') LIMIT 21; args=('2019-12-08 00:29:28.033564', '2okb8vdor5ydpa06vd97opvzhuqyxt51')
(0.000) SELECT "auth_user"."id", "auth_user"."password", "auth_user"."last_login", "auth_user"."is_superuser", "auth_user"."username", "auth_user"."first_name", "auth_user"."last_name", "auth_user"."email", "auth_user"."is_staff", "auth_user"."is_active", "auth_user"."date_joined" FROM "auth_user" WHERE "auth_user"."id" = 1 LIMIT 21; args=(1,)
```

Comment: Have you created an admin account?

Comment: @MatthewGaiser Yes I Have

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Its a Django 3.0 issue, multiple people have had the same problem. Try downgrading to another version, 2.2 works

Comment: Yes, there is an issue in Django 3.0 and above versions. I downgraded Django version to 2.2, It did work. Thanks...

Answer (score 0):

Have you checked the server logs and what does it say?

```
LOGGING = {
'version': 1,
'disable_existing_loggers': False,
'handlers': {
    'file': {
        'level': 'DEBUG',
        'class': 'logging.FileHandler',
        'filename': '/path/to/django/debug.log',
    },
},
'loggers': {
    'django': {
        'handlers': ['file'],
        'level': 'DEBUG',
        'propagate': True,
    },
},
```

}

Comment: I tried changing DB, ran it again, the admin login page was rendered, after entering the correct credentials, server shuts down again. same problem again.

Comment: Can you paste the content of the debug.log file ?

Comment: I added it as part of the question @Camillus

Answer (score 0):

I had the issue while using python 3.7 on mac, so I upgraded the virtualenv to use python 3.8 and the issue was resolved. I noticed it was also affecting sending emails via the app as well.